# Unhandled rejection Error: Cannot find module 'handlebars' in firebase hosting using express

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin  = require('firebase-admin');
const express = require('express');
const engines = require('consolidate');

const app  = express();

const firebaseApp = admin.initializeApp(
 functions.config().admin
);

app.engine('hbs', engines.handlebars); =>> this handlebars can't be loaded
app.set('views', './views');
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.get('/time', (req, res)=>{
 res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=300, s-maxage=600');
 res.render('index')
});
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

related to this project
[index.js](https://github.com/MASabbe/awilelang/blob/master/functions/index.js)

i am using expressjs in firebase hosting, firebase cli, i need view engine to get view tamplate hbs but i can't get the file

Answer (score 0):

From [consolidate's readme](https://github.com/tj/consolidate.js/blob/master/Readme.md):

> NOTE: you must still install the engines you wish to use, add them to
>   your package.json dependencies.

[Install handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/installation.html) by running, `npm install --save handlebars`.